# Heatmap of minimum, median, maximum values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

In the dataset below:

```
# Copy and paste the code below to get the dataframe output
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= {
    'Gen':['M','M','M','M','F','F','F','F','M','M','M','M','F','F','F','F'],
    'Site':['FRX','FX','FRX','FRX','FRX','FX','FRX','FX','FX','FX','FX','FRX','FRX','FRX','FRX','FRX'],
    'Type':['L','L','L','L','L','L','L','L','R','R','R','R','R','R','R','R'],
     'AIC':['<1','<1','<1','<1',1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,'>2','>2','>2','>2'],
     'AIC_TRX':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
     'diff':[-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3],
     'series':[1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8],
    'Grwth_Time1':[150.78,162.34,188.53,197.69,208.07,217.76,229.48,139.51,146.87,182.54,189.57,199.97,229.28,244.73,269.91,249.19],
     'Grwth_Time2':[250.78,262.34,288.53,297.69,308.07,317.7,329.81,339.15,346.87,382.54,369.59,399.97,329.28,347.73,369.91,349.12],
     'Grwth_Time3':[240.18,232.14,258.53,276.69,338.07,307.74,359.16,339.25,365.87,392.48,399.97,410.75,429.08,448.39,465.15,469.33],
     'Grwth_Time4':[270.84,282.14,298.53,306.69,318.73,327.47,369.63,389.59,398.75,432.18,449.78,473.55,494.85,509.39,515.52,539.23],
      'Grwth_Time5':[25.78,22.34,28.53,27.69,30.07,17.7,29.81,33.15,34.87,32.54,36.59,39.97,29.28,34.73,36.91,34.12],
     'Grwth_Time6':[240.18,232.14,258.53,276.69,338.07,307.74,359.16,339.25,365.87,392.48,399.97,410.75,429.08,448.39,465.15,469.33],
     'Grwth_Time7':[27.84,28.14,29.53,30.69,18.73,27.47,36.63,38.59,38.75,24.18,24.78,21.55,13.85,9.39,15.52,39.23],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns = ['Gen','Site','Type','AIC','AIC_TRX','diff','series','Grwth_Time1','Grwth_Time2','Grwth_Time3','Grwth_Time4','Grwth_Time5','Grwth_Time6','Grwth_Time7'])
df.info()

df2 = df.groupby(['series', 'AIC_TRX'])[['Grwth_Time1', 'Grwth_Time2', 'Grwth_Time3', 
        'Grwth_Time4', 'Grwth_Time5', 'Grwth_Time6', 'Grwth_Time7']].mean().unstack()
```

outputs:
[image]

I want to do the following:

1.create a heatmap based on the color shade/hue-

- max_value : green
- median_value : yellow
- minimum_value : red

2. Export the heatmap output as `.xlsx` file

My attempt:

```
# 
df2.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues').to_excel("output12272021.xlsx")
```

Desired output should look like the figure below, but using the `green`, `yellow`, `red` hue
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html check the docs to see if you can find the colour palette you are looking for, if this is the problem you are having. Editing the custom low/high values might work to start and then you can also set custom ones, like in the `cmap='YlOrRd'` example.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama, thanks for your attempt, I want to be able to control the `cmap` hue for the `min_value`, `median` and `max_value`....... `cmap='YlOrRd'` creates the heatmap hue, however, the shade does not reflect  the min, median and max  values accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom styler. The max and min values are easy to identify. The median is a problem though, as there may not be a value in the column that exactly equal the median. I'll leave it to you on how to identify that median cell.

```py
def styler(s: pd.Series) -> np.array:
    max_, median, min_ = s.agg(['max', 'median', 'min'])
    return np.select(
        [s == stat for stat in [max_, median, min_]],
        [f'background-color: {color}' for color in ['green', 'yellow', 'red']],
        ''
    )

df2.style.apply(styler, axis=0)
```

Output (before export to Excel):

[image: Custom pandas styler]

Comment: Difference, Thanks for your attempt. `yellow` is not reflected in the output. Also, I want a heatmap (all the values are colored according to how close they are to the `Max`, `Midpoint/median` and `Minimum values`) that shows various shades of `green`, `yellow` and `red`.  For example the minimum value should be a `solid red`, the next value to the minimum should be a lighter variation of red (pls refer to the desired output in the original post). Thanks